# If one blender crash, would the other get affected?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm currently rendering on Blender. which is taking some time.

I wanted to know, can I open up another blender file and work on that? if this 2nd Blender crashes, will it also crash the other Blender which is currently still rendering?

Comment: You can and it won't.

Comment: Even though it's true that if one Blender crashes the other won't be affected, you also need to take under consideration that sometimes it could happen that the crash could freezes the computer and you need to either kill the app or reboot the whole system

Comment: that's a good shout! @emir. Usually it's just blender for me. so if I could kill off 1 blender and keep the other going, that works with me! Just don't want the render to be effected. especially it normally takes days.

Comment: I'm not sure if I explained myself correctly, but basically, there is a 50% chance to affect your render if you put too much stress on your cpu because when you kill an app, you are killing the whole app, no matter how many you have open, they will all be closed

Comment: If you use up all your memory (RAM, but sometimes using whole disk space can have similar effects) it's quite possible you will have a cascade of crashes of other programs. So one Blender instance can crash Microsoft Office instance just as likely as another Blender instance. Unless there's some shared resource for Blender instances I don't know about.

Comment: @Markus von Broady. That's fine. I was more concerned about plugin/unknown crashes which what I sometimes get in other apps.  

I now feel much safer to operate in the other Blender without worrying if it would endanger my other Blender rendering. I never usually have the apps crushed via using all ram since I hardly use up all 32GB. but i do often end up 100% for my 3700X CPU for smoke type simulation cache which results in slow operating system. In that in stance, I wouldn't be able to do much anyway apart from surfing. (GPU render wise , 3090 seems fine for rendering + AAA gaming)